# Sampling uniformly from the convex cone

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, sampling

[image]Let $n$ vectors of dimension $d$ (e.g., $n = 100$, $d = 10000$), each with infinity norm of $1$, be given. The conic combination of those $n$ vectors generates a convex cone.
How to uniformly sample random points inside the convex cone (bounded by infinity norm of $1$)?
Note that rejection sampling does not work well for very large dimensions and number of vectors.
For example, consider the attached figure. Given $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $2d$, we want to uniformly generate black points.

Comment: A possible approach: first pick random coefficients of a conic combination, compute the corresponding random vector, and then pick a random point on the line segment of that vector.